# How to add an entry in a file (only if it doesn't exist) using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to add a json entry into a file in a specific position using Ansible and lineinfile + insertbefore.
This is a mock of the original file:

```
const var = 
{
    "values": [
        {
            "entry1":500,
            "entry2": "test001",
            "entry3": true
        },
        {
            "entry1":3,
            "entry2": "test002",
            "entry3": false
        }
    ]
};
```

The ansible script is this:

```
- name: script description 1
  lineinfile:
     dest: /destinationPATH/file.xpto
     insertbefore: "]"
     line: "\t\t,\t\t{\n\t\t\t'entry1':0,\n\t\t\t'entry2': 'ansible entry',\n\t\t\t'entry3': true\n\t\t}\n"
     state: present
     backup: yes
```

On the first try it works fine, adding the expected entry!

```
const var = 
{
    "values": [
        {
            "entry1": 500,
            "entry2": "test001",
            "entry3": true
        },
        {
            "entry1": 3,
            "entry2": "test002",
            "entry3": false
        }
        ,
        {
            "entry1": 0,
            "entry2": "ansible entry",
            "entry3": true
        }
    ]
};
```

The problem is that if I run twice, ... it adds that entry again...

```
const var = 
{
    "values": [
        {
            "entry1": 500,
            "entry2": "test001",
            "entry3": true
        },
        {
            "entry1": 3,
            "entry2": "test002",
            "entry3": false
        }
        ,
        {
            "entry1": 0,
            "entry2": "ansible entry",
            "entry3": true
        }
        ,
        {
            "entry1": 0,
            "entry2": "ansible entry",
            "entry3": true
        }
    ]
};
```

Tryed

```
- name: script description 2
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
    lineinfile:
        dest: /destinationPATH/file.xpto
        insertbefore: "]"
        line: "\t\t,\t\t{\n\t\t\t'entry1':0,\n\t\t\t'entry2': 'ansible entry',\n\t\t\t'entry3': true\n\t\t}\n"
        backup: yes
    check_mode: yes
```

and now the file isn't even changed...
Is there any way I can evaluate if that line exists in the file and if that is true then ansible adds it?

Comment: To achieve it with `lineinfile` you'll have to use multi-line `regexp`. You might be better off with `template`, or `blockinfile`. Next option would be to add the new item to "values" and `copy` `content` to the file.

Comment: You could use the shell module with cat and register the result to, in the end parse that result. But as @VladimirBotka says, using the template module would probably be easier.

Comment: I can't use the template option as I will not be able to control/know its content and changes in every version. The only thing I'm told is that I need to add the entry before the last ']' :(

Comment: Also tried adding check_mode: yes and with it file doesn't change with or without content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd break down the problem into two tasks.
I am assuming that your `ansible entry` is a unique string, that you can search for in the file.
So first, I would check if the entry exists in the file at all, like this:

```
 - name: Check if the file contains the entry
   shell: cat /destinationPATH/file.xpto | grep "ansible entry"
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo
   failed_when: false
   register: grep_result
```

The `grep_result` is a dictionary, that contains among other things the return code of the shell command, i.e. other than `0` in case it failed, which means the entry was not present.
`failed_when: false` makes it so that the play does not abort if that happens.

Then you could make your task dependend on the result using `when`, like this:

```
- name: script description 2
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  lineinfile:
    dest: /destinationPATH/file.xpto
    insertbefore: "]"
    line: "\t\t,\t\t{\n\t\t\t'entry1':0,\n\t\t\t'entry2': 'ansible entry',\n\t\t\t'entry3': true\n\t\t}\n"
    backup: yes
  when: grep_result.rc > 0
```